# SQL Query Help - query multiple tables with some returning empty values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out how to do this with a single query instead of a bunch.

I have 3 tables.

> Games (ID, GameName, Team1_id, Team2_id, datetime)
>
> GameResults (ID, game_ID, win_team, score)
>
> Teams(ID, team_name)

I want to return a query with that lists:
GameName, datetime, Team1.team_name, Team2.team_name, win_team, score.

However, I want to return all games and teams, even if there is NOT a `win_team` or score yet.  If I tie the table together with foreign keys, any games that do not have a record in the `GameResults` table will not show up.  I want all games, but some have not been played yet.  How do I return `GameResults` if there are some, but still return all the games even if there are no `GameResults` records?

I could just return all games, then loop through the results checking the `GameResults` table, but it seems like there would be a way to do this with a single query.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? And please add demo data and required output. See [how to create mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Use an `outer join`:

```
select g.gamename, g.datetime, t1.team_name, t2.team_name, gr.win_team, gr.score
from games g
   inner join teams t1 on g.team1_id = t1.id
   inner join teams t2 on g.team2_id = t2.id
   left join gameresults gr on g.id = gr.game_id
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that.  I was thinking joins but my brain started to hurt when I was trying to visualize it.... :)